# Move BufferedImage with Keys

Tags: java, move, bufferedimage

I have a background image on my 2D game, and I would like to know how I could move this image around with keys? I was trying things like:

```
background.getX() + 3;
```

But that wouldn't work as getX() isn't applicable for BufferedImages.

How can I do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need two things.

1. You're going to need to know the position of the image.  A simple `Point` object should suffice.  This tells you where to draw the image...
2. Some where to catch key board events.  For this I would suggest the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as it does not suffer from the same issues and `KeyListener`